# Packaging a large data file in a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to package a gem that relies on a large relational reference source, currently implemented as a 2.1GB sqlite database file.  I've placed the file in a /data directory and included it appropriately in the gemspec.  `gem build` works fine (although it takes half an hour to compress itself!), but `gem install` errors out:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RangeError)
    integer 2243380224 too big to convert to `int'
```

This would be totally cryptic, if I didn't notice that 2243380224 is the exact file size of the database. However, knowing that's the cause of the error doesn't bring me closer to a solution.

In the case at hand, it would not make sense to require users to separately download the database and specify it in their project configuration. I want `gem install` to deliver this functionality out of the box. Any suggestions on what best practice should be on packaging up ruby functionality that relies on mining a large information repository?

Comment: Maybe create some sort of script as part of the install process that downloads the DB independently, but still as part of the `gem install` process?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is coming from this [line](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb#L133) where rubygems tries to read the entry from the tar archive (a gem is basically a tar archive).

Not only is it trying to read the entry into memory in one go, but ruby's `IO.read` requires that its first argument fit into a signed long (not sure this is documented, but it's certainly what MRI does). On many common platforms, that means a 32 bit signed integer, max value 2**31-1, which is less than the size of your sqlite file.

You won't be able to install this gem without patching rubygems itself. Furthermore, since it does everything in memory (since it's expecting files to be smallish) you might run into memory allocation issues.

A gem can have a post install message, which you could use to prompt users to run your download script, but you can't run a script automatically (unless you abuse extconf.rb). Your users will probably thank you when minor code changes to your gem don't require them to re-download the 2GB data files.

Comment: I think the idea of a well-documented import script would work. I hate when an installer tries to download a lot more than I expect, or it takes longer than I expect; CNTRL+C gets hit a lot then. A script initiated by the user that shows progress during the transfer would go a long way toward giving me a warm and fuzzy feeling.